# How can i stop a dropdownlist from value change on selection in kendo/angular

Tags: angular, typescript, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I want the control of dropdown list value selection change. I want to stop the selected value change in the dropdownlist.

I have kendo dropdown list, on its triggering valueChange event.

```
<kendo-dropdownlist #dropdownlist required [data]="responseTypes" 
                                [defaultItem]="{responseTypeID: null, responseTypeName: 'Select Response Type'}"
                                [textField]="'responseTypeName'"
                                [valueField]="'responseTypeID'"
                                name="responseTypeId"
                                [(ngModel)]="selectedResponseType"
                                (valueChange)="responseTypeChange($event)"
                                #responseTypeIdVar="ngModel" class="form-control" style="width:180px;">

</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

Comment: So you are using ngModel with a 2 way binding and the binded value shouldn't change if the user selects another value?

Comment: @Geggi632: I am showing a kendo dialog confirmation box after every dropdown selection, but before the user can do 'Yes' or 'No' on the Dialog box the Dropdownlist value is changing to close state and displaying the changed selected value on the drop-down. I could see the value behind the Popup dialog is on the screen.

Comment: Change [(ngModel)] to [ngModel] and set the value, if accepted by the popup, to selectedResponseType.

Comment: @Geggi632 : I've already done that and it is working fine, but problem is when the dialog box is there on the screen. In the dropdownlist behind the popup under the overlay is getting changed to selected value, Then with 'Yes' or 'No' its working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution I got from Kendo Team using the **ChangeDetectorRef**. Called the **detectChanges** before reassigning **this.value**. The valueChange event is not preventable, you have to manually reset the value of the component as desired

[Click here for the example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zvumsy-htdqma)

Comment: Thanks @Srééjîth Náîr .

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best answer and I hope you will find a better one but it's working..

bindings:

```
<kendo-dropdownlist [value]="selectedVal"
  (valueChange)="valueChange($event)">
```

valueChange() code:

```
public valueChange(value: any): void {
    let valToShow = this.selectedVal;
    this.newVal = value;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.selectedVal = "changeToSomethingOther";
    }, 1);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.selectedVal = valToShow;
    }, 1);
    this.open('dialog');
    this.log('valueChange', value);
  }
```

What I'm doing is to change the binded value to something different and then back to the old value but you have to do it in setTimeOut to trigger the change detection.